# Google Apps Script - Global Variables alternative

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, global-variables, runtime

I'm using Google Apps Script to link many parts of Google Suites together. For example, I link a Google Form to a Spreadsheet which pulls data from another Spreadsheet to write onto the same Spreadsheet as well as create a Google Doc (convoluted I know). I've been using a lot of Global Variables simply because I need to keep track of the rows and columns of various Spreadsheets.

I was wondering whether there is another way of managing such global data because the script I've written is pretty long such that the initialization of the global variables takes a good 5-7 seconds.

It's interesting because I feel that Global Variables are good because it makes the code I write more readable but of course the tradeoff is increased run-time.

Comment: Storing globals in the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) can help cut down on runtime because those are only accessed when needed rather than initializing the data when the script loads.

Comment: If you are instantiating objects (like spreadsheets or form references) as globals, that's a bad practice. Store the string ID instead, and then open it only when you need the object.

Comment: @tehhowch I open the spreadsheet/form by it's ID and subsequently accessing the information I require on it. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: The question too broad as there are several alternatives to global variables. By the other hand it's unclear because there aren't enough details regarding how the global variables are being used, why they take "so long" to load and how the script is being used.

Comment: Also, there's a difference between storing a variable (like an ID) and getting the _data_ as a variable. You should only be calling the data when you need it, not as a global.

Comment: @Brian as i mentioned above, of course the most ideal thing to do would be to call the data only when it's needed according to the script. but because most of the data is being used for most of the scripts, calling the data when it's needed will decrease the readable of the code and there would be a lot of violation of DRY. so it's a dilemma for me :(